# collect bytes from string

Tags: arrays, rust, byte, buffer

This is decoded string from bytes, they are always different. Am not using it in the code, its just for shown what is all about.

```
"Random String; Tags:Value1:1,Value:2,Value3:value4"
```

This is array of bytes from above string which i get as input.

```
[&u8...&u8]
```

What i need is get the values fromthose. While every byte in the   array is changing. but some bytes are always same. I was thinking if there is any way how to extract it without using any Strings... Thanks for any ideas

so the output would look like this:

```
let v1 = [&u8, &u8, &u8, &u8, &u8];
let v2 = [&u8, &u8];
let v3 = [&u8];
let v4 = [&u8];
let v5 = [&u8];
```

Comment: Why is the output for `ELEMENT` also `ELEMENT`? It's the number after the dash for all the other keywords.

Comment: Dont mind the names, i just need to get those bytes from the array

Comment: I'm not talking about the names. You want `10` for `ATTACK`, `5` for `DEFENSE`, `4` for `HIGHNESS`, and `1` for `SWAG`, right? But you want `ELEMENT` for `ELEMENT` instead of `HYDRO`.

Comment: That was mistake probably i want hydro for it of course.. Sorry

Comment: Because SO isn't a code writing service, I won't just write the program for you. But here's some pointers: Byte slices, or `&[u8]` in Rust type notation, are very similar to `String`s. You can index them, iterate over them, they even have [a lot of methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) in common. If I were to do this, I'd probably start by finding all the `-` in the input and then checking whether they are preceded by one of the keywords. If so, get all the bytes after the `-` but before a `,` or `;`.

Comment: am not asking for code, i wanted to know how can i do that. Cause those bytes are chaning with every input. So i cant do it fixed.

Comment: Write a function that takes any `&[u8]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all this without allocating any extra space using rusts iterators, using `split` and related functions

At the top level, your data is of the form `(key:value;)*`
This suggests first splitting on `;`
Then splitting each of these pieces into key and value using `:`

In your case, all the information is when the `key` is `"tags"`.

Then within the tags section, you again have (mostly) key-value pairs of the form `(key-value,)*` so we need to split on `,` then break into key-value pairs using `-`.

An example that does this but only prints all the tag key-value pairs is:

```
fn split_kv(v: &[u8], c: u8) -> Option<(&[u8], &[u8])> {
    let n = v.iter().position(|&b| b == c)?;
    let w = v.split_at(n);
    Some((w.0, &(w.1)[1..]))
}

fn main() {
    let s: &str = "Background:Sunfire Topo;Base:Eagle;Accessory3:None;Patch:Oreo;Jacket:Pink Bonez;Eyes:BloodShot;Beak:Drool;Accessory2:Nose Ring;Accessory1:None;Item:Knife;tags:Dope Eagles,ELEMENT-HYDRO,ATTACK-10,DEFENSE-5,HIGHNESS-4,SWAG-1;metadata:QmU7JcFDoGcUvNkDgsPz9cy13md4xHdNyD6itwmgVLuo7x/860.json";
    let ss: &[u8] = s.as_bytes();

    let tags = ss
        .split(|&b| b == b';') // Break up at ';'
        .filter_map(|s| split_kv(s, b':')) // Split each piece into key-value pairs using ':'
        .filter_map(|(k, v)| { // Only keep the tags entry.
            if k == "tags".as_bytes() {
                Some(v)
            } else {
                None
            }
        }) 
        .next() // And just take the first of those.
        .unwrap(); 

    // Split the tags by ','
    for t in tags.split(|&b| b == b',') {
        // Then try to convert each to a key-value using '-' as seperator.
        if let Some((k, v)) = split_kv(t, b'-') {       
            println!(
                "k={:?} v={:?}",
                std::str::from_utf8(k).unwrap(),
                std::str::from_utf8(v).unwrap()
            );
        } else {
            println!("t={:?}", std::str::from_utf8(t).unwrap());
        }
    }
}
```

You can run this [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4a294c47440272e3559fa4d48b02a0aa)